# Saving customtkinter file inputs as a database file

Tags: python, database, user-interface, tkinter, customtkinter

I am new to GUIs in python and stack overflow. This is my first question.
I was trying to build a scoreboard GUI using customtkinter on my mac. However, my code needs to export all inputs given by the user as a database file. Can someone tell me how to do that? Is there a syntax for that?

I haven't tried anything yet because I have no clue where to start.
Also, if you want to know, I haven't built the code yet, only a small part of it.
If you need it: `

Comment: This question is far too broad for stackoveflow. Do you need help getting data out of a widget? Do you need help creating a database? Writing to a database? Something else? You should be able to find multiple examples of all of that on the internet.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.